# Trying to understand the Git Workflow

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket

I'm really obsessional with the fact that my workflow isn't that productive as I want.

I search all over the internet "HOW TO USE GIT" , well that was a search for experts, a lot of tutorials for really brillant devs.

then I search "HOW TO USE GIT FOR AN OPTIMAL WORKFLOW", that help , now I can use Github, Bitbucker and now I know how to commit , push, pull from TOWER or GitApp, and some times I do terminal.

But that doesn't resolve my workflow issues.

I still developing sometimes live , using "on save upload to FTP" in SublimeText, some of my teammates can't use the same Sass at the same time, and well everything is a mess.

I decide to start training my self to learn how to use well git. So I start my search in google "Git for Dummies".

Guess what?! , that was technical for me also , but I learned the next thing:

I have this site: git.dev in my local home machine :Local Repository
I have this private repository in BitBucket.
and I have Live Server in Linode.

So what I start doing is developing my websites locally , pushing it to bitbucket so my teammates can clone it to make changes.

Then when everything is Right we push it to the Live Server.

I think there is a lost link on this idea, because I have the Dev-Environment(Local Machine) , the Backup-Environment(Bitbucket) , the Live-Environment , but I think a Test-Environment is needed.

Am I understanding things well?.

Can someone be so kind of guide me to the correct source of light.

Thnanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read through these links?

https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows
https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-a-good-git-workflow